# Can Grafana panel show a fixed time range each day?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

In grafana time series, We can use relative time `now/d` to show today's data distribution.

For some reason I want to spilit one day's data and show them in seperate panels. Please take this as an example to understand:

In one grafana row, I display 5 panels. The first one shows data from today's 0:00 to 9:30,
the second one shows data from today's 9:30 to 11:30, etc.

Note that the rime range must change by day. So basically I want some way to implement the function like `now/d` but a split version of `now/d`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can specify Relative time of panel to `now/d+9h` for it to start at 9:00, but I don't think you can do the same for end range of panel. AFAIK,  only relative shifts for it are available.

Comment: @markalex thx for replying, i think I'll try other ways